# output a column group by another column shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a pathway.text file. The columns are separated by "\t".
The first column and second column are like:

```
Y123W    AB - CD - ED    ...  
Y948W    ED - WG - SG -EG  ...  
Y9368    AB - UE  ...  
Y024W    AB - UE  ...  
YOWB3    AB - CD - ED  ...  
...
```

I want to output elements in the first columns group by unique elements in the second column. It should be like (the format doesn't matter):

```
AB - CD - ED:
Y123W, YOWB3, ...
AB - UE:
Y9368, Y024W, ...
ED - WG - SG -EG:
Y948W, ...
...
```

I first tried to read second column into an array:

```
pathways=( $(awk -F"\t" '{print $2}' pathway.txt) )
```

Then I tried to sort the pathways to get unique pathways:

```
uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${pathways[@]}" | sort -u))
```

However, maybe because the elements of second column contain spaces " ", so the array *uniq* I got was in a mess.

```
echo "${uniq[@]}"
```

The output is like:

```
AB AB AB AB CD CD ...
```

I am new with shell. So i just tried to achieve it step by step with what I would do with python or R... Please help! Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the total number of columns? how should the remaining columns be grouped?

Comment: There are around 200 columns. The proteins(first column) are supposed to be grouped by the corresponding pathways(the second column). @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{if ($2 in a) a[$2]=a[$2]", "$1; else a[$2]=$2":\n"$1} END{for (x in a)print a[x]}' file
AB - UE:
Y9368, Y024W
ED - WG - SG -EG:
Y948W
AB - CD - ED:
Y123W, YOWB3
```

#### How it works

- `-F'\t'`

  This sets the field separator to a tab.
- `if ($2 in a) a[$2]=a[$2]", "$1; else a[$2]=$2":\n"$1`

  If the second field is already in array `a`, then append on the current field 1.  If it isn't, then start a new entry in `a`.
- `END{for (x in a)print a[x]}`

  After we have read the entire input file, print out the results.

#### Alternative

This version uses a ternary statement in the place of the `if-else` statement.

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{a[$2]=a[$2](a[$2]?", "$1:$1)} END{for (x in a)printf "%s:\n%s\n",x,a[x]}' file
AB - UE:
Y9368, Y024W
ED - WG - SG -EG:
Y948W
AB - CD - ED:
Y123W, YOWB3
```